# How to discover which device is the display frame buffer device of an embedded Linux hardware

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, framebuffer

I want to install the tslib in an embedded Linux hardware.

But I don't know which device is the "frame buffer" needed to set TSLIB_FBDEVICE.

/dev folder:

```
/dev $ ls -la
drwxr-xr-x   10 root     root         13704 Jun 11 15:03 .
drwxr-xr-x   16 root     root          1400 Mar 25 15:52 ..
crw-rw----    1 root     root      189, 258 Jun 11 15:03 3-1
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root      215,   0 Nov 23  2018 PowerManager
crwxrwxrwx    1 root     root      130,   0 Nov 23  2018 cadrv
crwxrwxrwx    1 root     root      131,   0 Jan  1  1970 causb
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root      205,   0 Nov 23  2018 clcd
crwxrwxrwx    1 root     root      133,   0 Jan  1  1970 cldrv
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        5,   1 Jun 11 15:27 console
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       10,  70 Nov 23  2018 crypto
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root      201,   0 Nov 23  2018 csx_iod
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root      207,   0 Nov 23  2018 dd
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            14 Jan 28 11:34 dsp -> /dev/sound/dsp
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root      221,   0 Nov 23  2018 ept0
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root       29,   0 Nov 23  2018 fb0
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root      202,   0 Nov 23  2018 fb_dma
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root       10, 229 Nov 23  2018 fuse
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root      204,   0 Nov 23  2018 fuse_ipc
drwxrwxr-x    2 root     root           288 Mar 20  2012 fusion
drwxrwxr-x    2 root     root           160 Mar 20  2012 gadget
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root      203,   0 Nov 23  2018 ge
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root      209,   0 Nov 23  2018 gpio
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root        3,   0 Nov 23  2018 hda
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root        3,   1 Nov 23  2018 hda1
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root        3,  10 Nov 23  2018 hda10
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root        3,  11 Nov 23  2018 hda11
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root        3,  12 Nov 23  2018 hda12
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root        3,  13 Nov 23  2018 hda13
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root        3,  14 Nov 23  2018 hda14
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root        3,  15 Nov 23  2018 hda15
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root        3,   2 Nov 23  2018 hda2
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root        3,   3 Nov 23  2018 hda3
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root        3,   4 Nov 23  2018 hda4
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root        3,   5 Nov 23  2018 hda5
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root        3,   6 Nov 23  2018 hda6
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root        3,   7 Nov 23  2018 hda7
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root        3,   8 Nov 23  2018 hda8
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root        3,   9 Nov 23  2018 hda9
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       10, 183 Nov 23  2018 hw_random
crwxrwxrwx    1 root     root       89,   0 Nov 23  2018 i2c-0
crwxrwxrwx    1 root     root       89,   1 Jan  1  1970 i2c-1
drwxrwxr-x    2 root     root           608 Mar 20  2012 input
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root      219,   0 Nov 23  2018 iodump
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root      222,   0 Nov 23  2018 keypad0
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root      222,   1 Nov 23  2018 keypad1
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root        1,   2 Nov 23  2018 kmem
crwxrwxrwx    1 root     root      129,   0 Nov 23  2018 kmodem
crwxrwxrwx    1 root     root      127,   0 Nov 23  2018 kmsdrv
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root      223,   0 Nov 23  2018 lcd
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root      216,   0 Nov 23  2018 led
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            13 Dec 10  2015 log -> /var/log/.log
brw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        7,   0 Nov 23  2018 loop0
brw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        7,   1 Nov 23  2018 loop1
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            22 Jan  1  1970 mdev.seq -> /mnt/ramdisk1/mdev.seq
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root        1,   1 Nov 23  2018 mem
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            16 Jan 28 11:34 mixer -> /dev/sound/mixer
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root      179,   0 Nov 23  2018 mmcblk0
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root      179,   1 Nov 23  2018 mmcblk0p1
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root      179,  10 Nov 23  2018 mmcblk0p10
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root      179,   2 Nov 23  2018 mmcblk0p2
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root      179,   3 Nov 23  2018 mmcblk0p3
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root      179,   4 Nov 23  2018 mmcblk0p4
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root      179,   5 Nov 23  2018 mmcblk0p5
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root      179,   6 Nov 23  2018 mmcblk0p6
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root      179,   7 Nov 23  2018 mmcblk0p7
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root      179,   8 Nov 23  2018 mmcblk0p8
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root      179,   9 Nov 23  2018 mmcblk0p9
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root      202,   0 Nov 23  2018 mmdma
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,   0 Nov 23  2018 mtd0
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,   1 Nov 23  2018 mtd0-ro
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,   2 Nov 23  2018 mtd1
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,   3 Nov 23  2018 mtd1-ro
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,  20 Nov 23  2018 mtd10
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,  21 Nov 23  2018 mtd10-ro
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,  22 Nov 23  2018 mtd11
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,  23 Nov 23  2018 mtd11-ro
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,  24 Nov 23  2018 mtd12
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,  25 Nov 23  2018 mtd12-ro
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,  26 Nov 23  2018 mtd13
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,  27 Nov 23  2018 mtd13-ro
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,  28 Nov 23  2018 mtd14
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,  29 Nov 23  2018 mtd14-ro
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,  30 Nov 23  2018 mtd15
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,  31 Nov 23  2018 mtd15-ro
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,   4 Nov 23  2018 mtd2
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,   5 Nov 23  2018 mtd2-ro
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,   6 Nov 23  2018 mtd3
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,   7 Nov 23  2018 mtd3-ro
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,   8 Nov 23  2018 mtd4
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,   9 Nov 23  2018 mtd4-ro
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,  10 Nov 23  2018 mtd5
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,  11 Nov 23  2018 mtd5-ro
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,  12 Nov 23  2018 mtd6
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,  13 Nov 23  2018 mtd6-ro
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,  14 Nov 23  2018 mtd7
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,  15 Nov 23  2018 mtd7-ro
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,  16 Nov 23  2018 mtd8
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,  17 Nov 23  2018 mtd8-ro
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,  18 Nov 23  2018 mtd9
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,  19 Nov 23  2018 mtd9-ro
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root       31,   0 Nov 23  2018 mtdb-boot1
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root       31,   1 Nov 23  2018 mtdb-boot2
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root       31,   2 Nov 23  2018 mtdb-ctrl
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root       31,   4 Nov 23  2018 mtdb-k0
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root       31,   5 Nov 23  2018 mtdb-k1
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root       31,   3 Nov 23  2018 mtdb-nvdata
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root       31,   6 Nov 23  2018 mtdb-root0
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root       31,   7 Nov 23  2018 mtdb-root1
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root       31,   0 Nov 23  2018 mtdblock0
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root       31,   1 Nov 23  2018 mtdblock1
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root       31,   2 Nov 23  2018 mtdblock2
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root       31,   3 Nov 23  2018 mtdblock3
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root       31,   4 Nov 23  2018 mtdblock4
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root       31,   5 Nov 23  2018 mtdblock5
brw-rw-r--    1 root     root       31,   6 Nov 23  2018 mtdblock6
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,   0 Nov 23  2018 mtdc-boot1
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,   1 Nov 23  2018 mtdc-boot1-ro
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,   2 Nov 23  2018 mtdc-boot2
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,   3 Nov 23  2018 mtdc-boot2-ro
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,   4 Nov 23  2018 mtdc-ctrl
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,   5 Nov 23  2018 mtdc-ctrl-ro
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,   8 Nov 23  2018 mtdc-k0
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,   9 Nov 23  2018 mtdc-k0-ro
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,  10 Nov 23  2018 mtdc-k1
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,  11 Nov 23  2018 mtdc-k1-ro
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,   6 Nov 23  2018 mtdc-nvdata
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,   7 Nov 23  2018 mtdc-nvdata-ro
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,  12 Nov 23  2018 mtdc-root0
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,  13 Nov 23  2018 mtdc-root0-ro
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,  14 Nov 23  2018 mtdc-root1
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       90,  15 Nov 23  2018 mtdc-root1-ro
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        1,   3 Nov 23  2018 null
drwxrwxr-x    2 root     root           160 Mar 20  2012 oprofile
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root      211,   0 Nov 23  2018 otp
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root      225,   0 Nov 23  2018 pmu
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root      108,   0 Nov 23  2018 ppp
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root       10,   1 Nov 23  2018 psaux
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        5,   2 Nov 23  2018 ptmx
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 pts
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root        2,   0 Nov 23  2018 ptyp0
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root        2,   1 Nov 23  2018 ptyp1
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root        2,   2 Nov 23  2018 ptyp2
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root        2,   3 Nov 23  2018 ptyp3
brw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        1,   1 Nov 23  2018 ram
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root        1,   8 Nov 23  2018 random
crwxrwxrwx    1 root     root      254,   0 Nov 23  2018 rtc
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             9 Dec 10  2015 rtc0 -> /tmp/rtc0
crwxrwxrwx    1 root     root      132,   0 Nov 23  2018 scdrv
brw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        8,   0 Nov 23  2018 sda
brw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        8,   1 Nov 23  2018 sda1
brw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        8,   2 Nov 23  2018 sda2
brw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        8,   3 Nov 23  2018 sda3
brw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        8,  16 Nov 23  2018 sdb
brw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        8,  17 Nov 23  2018 sdb1
brw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        8,  18 Nov 23  2018 sdb2
brw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        8,  19 Nov 23  2018 sdb3
brw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        8,  32 Nov 23  2018 sdc
brw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        8,  48 Nov 23  2018 sdd
crwxrwxrwx    1 root     root      126,   0 Nov 23  2018 security
drwxrwxrwt    2 root     root            80 Jun 11 12:07 shm
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root      232,   0 Nov 23  2018 sim
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     root           504 Jan 28 11:34 snd
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     root           480 Jan 28 11:34 sound
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root             0 Mar 20  2012 sysupd
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        5,   0 Nov 23  2018 tty
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        4,   0 Nov 23  2018 tty0
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        4,   1 Nov 23  2018 tty1
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        4,   2 Nov 23  2018 tty2
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        4,   3 Nov 23  2018 tty3
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root      166,   0 Jun 11 15:03 ttyACM0
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root      166,   1 Jun 11 15:03 ttyACM1
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root      166,   2 Jun 11 15:03 ttyACM2
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root      166,   3 Jun 11 15:03 ttyACM3
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root      166,   4 Jun 11 15:03 ttyACM4
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root      166,   5 Jun 11 15:03 ttyACM5
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root      204,  64 Nov 23  2018 ttyAMA0
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root      204,  65 Nov 23  2018 ttyAMA1
crwxrwxrwx    1 root     root      251,   0 Jun 11 15:28 ttyGS
crw-rw----    1 root     root      251,   0 Mar 11 11:38 ttyGS0
crwxrwxrwx    1 root     root        4,  64 Nov 23  2018 ttyS0
crwxrwxrwx    1 root     root        4,  65 Mar 25 10:41 ttyS1
crwxrwxrwx    1 root     root        4,  66 Nov 23  2018 ttyS2
crwxrwxrwx    1 root     root        4,  67 Nov 23  2018 ttyS3
crwxrwxrwx    1 root     root      188,   0 Nov 23  2018 ttyUSB0
crwxrwxrwx    1 root     root      188,   1 Nov 23  2018 ttyUSB1
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root      127,   0 Nov 23  2018 ttygserial
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root        3,   0 Nov 23  2018 ttyp0
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root        3,   1 Nov 23  2018 ttyp1
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root        3,   2 Nov 23  2018 ttyp2
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root        3,   3 Nov 23  2018 ttyp3
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root      251,   0 Nov 23  2018 ubi0
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root      251,   2 Nov 23  2018 ubi0_1
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             9 Dec 10  2015 ubi1 -> /tmp/ubi1
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             9 Dec 10  2015 ubi2 -> /tmp/ubi2
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             9 Dec 10  2015 ubi3 -> /tmp/ubi3
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root       10,  60 Nov 23  2018 ubi_ctrl
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root      206,   0 Nov 23  2018 udchp
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root        1,   9 Nov 23  2018 urandom
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root      235,   0 Nov 23  2018 usb-i2c
crw-rw----    1 root     root      189, 258 Apr 10 11:09 usbdev3.3
crw-rw----    1 root     root        7,   2 Jun 10 12:11 vcs2
crw-rw----    1 root     root        7,   3 Jun 10 12:11 vcs3
crw-rw----    1 root     root        7, 130 Jun 10 12:11 vcsa2
crw-rw----    1 root     root        7, 131 Jun 10 12:11 vcsa3
crw-rw-r--    1 root     root       81,   0 Nov 23  2018 video
crw-rw----    1 root     root       10, 130 Nov 23  2018 watchdog
crw-rw-rw-    1 root     root        1,   5 Nov 23  2018 zero
```

If I try to use /dev/fb0 it returns no such device:

```
/dev $ hexdump fb0
hexdump: fb0: No such device
```

/proc/devices:

```
/proc $ cat devices
Character devices:
  1 mem
  2 pty
  3 ttyp
  4 /dev/vc/0
  4 tty
  4 ttyS
  5 /dev/tty
  5 /dev/console
  5 /dev/ptmx
  7 vcs
 10 misc
 13 input
 14 sound
 21 sg
 29 fb
 81 video4linux
 89 i2c
 90 mtd
108 ppp
116 alsa
126 security
127 kmsdrv
128 ptm
130 cadrv
132 scdrv
133 cldrv
136 pts
166 ttyACM
180 usb
188 ttyUSB
189 usb_device
209 user-gpio
216 rfcomm
235 sysevent
251 ttyGS
252 hidraw
253 ubi0
254 rtc

Block devices:
  1 ramdisk
257 ssfdc
259 blkext
  7 loop
  8 sd
 31 mtdblock
 43 nbd
 65 sd
 66 sd
 67 sd
 68 sd
 69 sd
 70 sd
 71 sd
128 sd
129 sd
130 sd
131 sd
132 sd
133 sd
134 sd
135 sd
179 mmc
```

/proc/fb:

```
/proc $ cat fb
0 BCM5892 LCD
```

Is there a file that points to default display device?
Or a shell script that initializes this device?

Qt applications can display without problems in this hardware,

Thanks,